# Get variables from a settings.py file in a Jinja template with Flask

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

Say I have settings.py file with a bunch of constants (maybe more, in the future). How do I access those variables in a Jinja template?

Comment: It is a possible duplicated question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7104198/flask-accessing-the-config-variable-in-the-template

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Flask automatically includes your application's config in the [standard context](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/templating/#standard-context). So if you used `app.config.from_envvar` or `app.config.from_pyfile` to pull in the values from your settings file, you already have access to those values in your Jinja templates (e.g., `{{ config.someconst }}`).

Comment: i'm not able to do this, maybe its outdated for 2023, restarted my serve, tried everything already

Answer (score 7):

You need to define a `context_processor`:

```
@app.context_processor
def inject_globals():
    return dict(
        const1 = const1,
        const2 = const2,
    )
```

Values injected this way will be directly available in templates:

```
<p>The values of const1 is {{ const1 }}.</p>
```

You'll probably want to use the Python `dir` function to avoid listing all of the constants.

Comment: Thanks. So can I access them in all the templates automatically? (e.g. `{{ g.const1 }}`)

Comment: @john2x: The constants will be available directly, see my updated answer. But I think ddbeck's answer may better suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks. I guess `app.config` is the "standard" way?

Comment: they are not available in macros. why??