# Flask - Accessing the config variable in the template

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am using Flask version 0.7.  I have stored the path of static content in a configuration file and loaded it using

```
app.config.from_envvar(<file_name>)
```

Can I be able to access this config variable in the template without passing the variables through the view?

Comment: I used app.config.from_pyfile(<file_name>) to load the configuration to flask config variable. Since Flask 0.6; config, being one of the global variable, is available in Jinja2 templates by default. Then the config variables can be easily accessed as a  dictionary object in the templates.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

There are a few global variables that are passed in the templates context by default by flask ([here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/templating/#standard-context) is the complete list), one of them being `config`, which allows you to access the application configuration from templates.  Being a dictionary, it can be accessed using the syntax `config['MY_CONFIGURATION']` or `config.MY_CONFIGURATION` (this syntax for accessing dict items is specific to Jinja).

On the other hand, if you wanted to pass arbitrary data to your templates without having to pass it explicitely in each view, you would have to use [context processors](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/templating/#context-processors).

Comment: I'd just like to note that "Only values in uppercase are actually stored in the config object"; this gave me a few minutes of confusion when faced with the same question as the poster.

Comment: Don't forget to reload Flask if you are storing your config values in a Python file in debug mode, changes in this file are not watched.

Comment: Example usage in template: `{{ config.MY_CONFIGURATION }}`

Comment: This simple solution works fine. To check how this solution integrates with Docker, one could check out this [post](http://docker.lhsm.com.br/6641cdd6-346f-4f17-be6d-4ae954010d92).

Comment: doesn't work anymore, any update?