# Using content delivery networks with Flask

Tags: python, cdn, flask, jinja2

Is there a way to have something similar to Djangos `{{ MEDIA_URL }}` tag in a Flask application?

Originally I simply wanted to use the `static_url_path` option for this, but Werkzeug won't create url route for paths that doesn't start with '/'. This seems reasonable enough when I thought about it a bit more.

The second option, that does work, but which I dislike, is to simply parse a `MEDIA_URL` variable to every single `render_template`. I would like my solution to be a bit more automatic, if that's possible.

Is there a way to inject a variable into every single jinja2 template in advance or do I have to live with either parsing my `MEDIA_URL` to very template or hardcode the img, css and javascript paths into my templates?

Comment: Found the answer 30 seconds after posting the question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7017990/get-variables-from-a-settings-py-file-in-a-jinja-template-with-flask

Comment: you should post the answer and accept it - it will help others with the same problem :-)